# Cambiar pagina de error de react en producción

Tags: reactjs

En modo desarrollo cuando hay un error sale esta pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero cuando esta en producción sale en blanco, ¿Hay una forma de cambiarla este en producción y poder modificarla para que envés de mostrar codigo sea como un formulario de reporte de error

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama "error boundaries" lo puedes encontrar acá https://es.reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: Si eso había visto aunque al principio no me funciono, luego seguí el ejemplo que ponía y pude, lo único "malo" es que al estar el prodición me mostrara el error en el bundle

Comment: Error boundaries te da la posibilidad de personalizar el error en producción, puedes agregar una bonita pantalla al usuario o incluso enviar ese error a tu servidor, en la actualidad lo utilizo y te puedo decir que es en verdad una muy buena opción. Puedes pasarte por este blog https://blog.logrocket.com/react-error-handling-react-error-boundary/